# mremap returns size, but should return a valid pointer

Tags: linux, memory, memory-management, shared-memory, mmap

According to the mremap documentation (https://www.man7.org/linux/man-pages//man2/mremap.2.html), "On success mremap() returns a pointer to the new virtual memory area.  On error, the value MAP_FAILED (that is, (void *) -1) is returned, and errno is set appropriately."

Below is my code for mremap.  On entry the values are set as follows:

```
old_address:  (void *) 0x7ffff4957000 (140737296822272)
old_size:  8003584
new_size:  16007168
```

After the call, the pointer return_ptr is (void *) 0x7a2000, which is the old_size value (8003584), not a valid  pointer value.

Here is the code:

```
void * remap_shm(void *old_address, size_t old_size, size_t new_size)
{

    void * return_ptr;

    return_ptr = mremap(old_address, old_size, new_size, MAP_PRIVATE | MREMAP_MAYMOVE);

    if (return_ptr <= 0){
        printf("Error on remap! %s\n", strerror(errno)); }

    return return_ptr;
}
```

If I omit the MREMAP_MAYMOVE flag it fails.

I'm very mystified.  Can anyone explain why I get the old_size value returned as the pointer to the new memory mapping?

Thanks.

Comment: Pilcrow's answer has explained the value of the return value,  I would however except return value to still be valid pointer (but parts of your program may be missing).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Omit MAP_PRIVATE.

MAP_PRIVATE is not a valid flag for `mremap`.  On my system, MAP_PRIVATE == MREMAP_FIXED, which means that `mremap` would mistakenly [expect a fifth argument](https://www.man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/mremap.2.html), which you do not provide.

Comment: Yes, you're right.  Now I get a pointer value.  I'm surprised that MAP_PRIVATE would make it fixed by default.